# Casting a list of an object to another with implicit conversion

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, implicit-conversion

I have two objects `myObject1` and `myObject2`, in myObject1 I have the following method:

```
public static implicit operator myObject2(myObject1 param)
{ //Some Code }
```

How can I cast an `IEnumerable<myObject1>` to `IEnumerable<myObject2>`?

Comment: do they have same properties?

Comment: The implementation of the cast is done, but writing something like `IEnumerable<myObject2> params2 = params1` doesn't compile, given params1 is `IEnumerable<myObject1>`

Comment: what makes you think it will compile? you declared a conversion operator from `myObject1` to `myObject2` not from `IEnumerable<myOjbect1>` to `IEnumerable<myObject2>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try provoking a cast on each item:

```
IEnumerable<myObject1> original; 
// ...
IEnumerable<myObject2> converted = original.Cast<myObject2>();
```

Comment: I tried this and the compiler is trying to convert the whole IEnumerable instead of the objects within, so it doesn't compile.

Comment: It compiles and works for me. A new `IEnumerable<myObject2>` will be created; you can't assign to the same collection because it's a different type.

Comment: Oh yess... noobie mistake, I was declaring the assigned type as List<myObject2> which of course couldn't take the IEnumerable being given. It works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var converted = original.Select(o=>(myObject2)o);
```

Comment: This works although I'm not sure how it might impact performance vs. the `Cast<>()` method.